# Cloud Structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cloud

I'm trying to create a cloud base app that allows users to save customers with their phones, addresses, emails, dates of birth, notes and more. Using PHP and SQL.
Let's say that the app has 100,000 users and each of them have 100 customers registered. What would be the best structure; share one Database to all of them saving every customer created and their information in the same tables of this Database, or create a new Database for each of them.

I hope you can help me out guys. Thanks!

Comment: One database with a `user` table and a `customer` table that includes a user_id.... 1,000,000 records in a `customer` table isn't particularly big as long as it's properly indexed; but 100,000 databases is a lot to manage if ever you change the application and datatables

Comment: So, It won't be too much delay if 10,000 users online request their information into 10,000,000 of records?.

Comment: As long as you design your database properly then this is something you should worry about when you actually start seeing performance problems. Optimizing stuff like this without actually having the numbers you are dreaming of is not particularly useful. Without that kind of traffic you cannot know where problems will arise.

Comment: If that's concurrent, then you might actually need to do some database optimisation to handle every single user requesting every single piece of data in the database at the same time, though the likelihood of that is likely to be pretty slim..... of course, if you have 100,000 databases all on one server, with every user requesting every piece of information held all at the same time, you'd have problems